# Azure with Xamarin.Android "You must be logged in to use this application"

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am recently starting to learn mobile development for my Final Year Project, and I am doing an Android application using Xamarin.Android and Azure Mobile Services.
I have created a Test DB and created one entry there, trying to make my Android App to connect to the DB and retrieve this entry. I am doing this to get an idea how to establish a connection and retrieve data, and from there I will start modification properly.
That is how my Model class look like (note that JSON properties are named exactly like the columns names in my DB.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace com.parkkl.intro.Models
{
    class TestTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleted")]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
        public string Creation { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updatedAt")]
        public string Updated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And that is how my activity look like

```
using Android.App;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Android.OS;
using com.parkkl.intro.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Widget;

namespace com.parkkl.intro
{
    [Activity(Label = "ParkKL", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        #region Variables
        public static MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient
            (@"http://parkkl.azurewebsites.net/");
        private IMobileServiceTable<TestTable> test = null;
        private List<TestTable> testItems;
        #endregion

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            test = client.GetTable<TestTable>();

            testItems = new List<TestTable>();

            GetData();

        }

        public async void GetData()
        {
            var collection = await test.Where(user => user.Id == 1).ToCollectionAsync();

            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                testItems.Add(
                    new TestTable
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        UserName = item.UserName,
                        Deleted = item.Deleted,
                        Version = item.Version,
                        Creation = item.Creation,
                        Updated = item.Updated,
                    });
            }
            var finalItem = collection[0];
            TextView text = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextFromDB);
            text.Append(finalItem.UserName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, every time I try to deploy the app, it throws this exception

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:
>   You must be logged in to use this application

In my App Service in Azure, I have disabled all authentications, still I get this error. I am wondering where the issue is coming from?! I will much appreciate your help.

EDIT: I guess I found the issue, which was the permissions given on the table itself. However, I am still finding out a way to authenticate my app properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the book http://aka.ms/zumobook for details on how to deal with authentication.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I have gone a little bit through the book, and it is really comprehensive and clear. It will help me so much.
I just have a question aside from this. How or what is the best strategy to register new users to my app, by using Azure web service. Is this part covered in the book or need more research?!

I really appreciate sharing the book.

Comment: It really depends on your situation - there is no "best" strategy.    It isn't covered in the book as a result.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, actually I have just came across your blog here (https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/) and to be honest, that is incredible work really. I guess all I need is there, so thanks a lot for your help Adrian.